# Shopify / Rails App: Where do I call a method that I want to run immediately after installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've built a Shopify app on Rails using shopify_app gem. I want to call a method immediately after a store owner installs the app, but I'm having trouble figuring out where I would call that.

What is the controller#action when a new instance of the app is created?

I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ShopifyApp::Controller
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end


class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :login_again_if_different_shop
  around_filter :shopify_session
  layout ShopifyApp.configuration.embedded_app? ? 'embedded_app' : 'application'
end


class HomeController < AuthenticatedController
  def index
    @customers = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 100})
  end
end


class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::SessionsController
end
```

Comment: Should this run every time the app restarts on only when being installed?

Comment: @AntarrByrd any ideas?

Comment: I would probably just create a task that the installer can run. There are probably other thinks you can do similar to configuring a cms.